# Eclipse Android Imported existing projects Accidently replaced and project all gone

Tags: java, android, decompiling, dex2jar, apktool

I updated the ADT and imported the projects. Unfortunately, I replaced the projects/folder.
All of sudden, all the files in the folder became 0 bytes, including files in sub folders and all the current auto backups. Is there any other way to recover?and why this all 0bytes happened?

I had tested decompiling my apk from mobile with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6081365/1009225)  and Differente decompilers. but, couldn't all the codes and obstucted codes. and most of the decompiler resulted errors.

Comment: ... and you don't have a backup...

Comment: I had the back up with my src folder every time I edit, but, bad luck all in sub folders and these sub folder also 0bytes.

Comment: You should have made a zip of your complete project folder (and put it OUTSIDE your workspace). You should make a backup every time you are going to change anything. Or (at least) once a day. At least, you learned a lesson for the future.

Comment: It is a good lesson.Yes, I had a rar files into another hard disk. I lost my 1 month work. Sad but True. In my Workspace folder almost folders are 511bytes.

what really happened?

Comment: `what really happened?` I really can't tell... And I doubt that any undelete/recovery tool are so effective, but you can try to (at least) partially recover some files.

Comment: Yes, you cannot tell. I should be RARing all the files out-of-workspace.

I don't understand why ADT has to make non related files to 0bytes.
Very sad.

Comment: Something unpredictable went wrong. As always, prevention helps curing. I hope you are starting to behave like if "A backup a day keeps blasphemy away"... ;)

Comment: Thank you! Surely be backuping `OUTSIDE workspace`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what happened to your project but you can try to **Restore from Local history** :

```
Package Explorer view > Right click on file/project > Restore from Local history
```